# I need to update SharePoint online document library properties using REST API C#. But I keep getting 400(Bad request) error

Tags: c#, rest, api, sharepoint-online

My Url is correct. When I search using browser it gives me the file.

```
https://sharepoint.com/sites/sitecollection/_api/web/GetFileByServerRelativeUrl('/sites/sitecollection/DocumentLibraryName/file.txt')/ListItemAllFields
```

Is the way I update wrong?

```
System.Net.HttpWebRequest wreq = HttpWebRequest.Create(resourceUrl) as HttpWebRequest;

wreq.UseDefaultCredentials = false;          
wreq.Credentials = credential;
wreq.CookieContainer = GetO365CookieContainer(credential, webUrl);
wreq.UserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 9.0; Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/5.0)";

string formDigest = GetFormDigestValue(webUrl, credential, wreq.CookieContainer);

wreq.Method = "POST";
wreq.Accept = "application/json;odata=verbose";
wreq.ContentType = "application/json;odata=verbose";
wreq.Headers.Add("X-HTTP-Method", "MERGE");
wreq.Headers.Add("IF-MATCH", "*");
wreq.Headers.Add("X-RequestDigest", formDigest);


string stringData = "{'__metadata': { 'type': 'SP.Data.DocumentsItem' }, 'Description': 'Added'}";
byte[] byteArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(stringData);
wreq.ContentLength = stringData.ToString().Length;
StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(wreq.GetRequestStream());
writer.Write(stringData);
writer.Flush();
```

Comment: The SharePoint client APIS and SDKs are well documented. Check the [Complete basic operations using SharePoint client library code] article in the docs. The [Update a List item](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/sp-add-ins/complete-basic-operations-using-sharepoint-client-library-code#update-a-list-item) example shows how to update a list item in just 6 lines

Comment: BTW making an HTTP call is *far* easier than the code's question. There's no reason to use a raw HttpWebRequest, you can use HttpClient. Even if you do, you don't have to a string to bytes or use a stream to send it as UTF8, the HttpWebRequest object will do that. Finally, that `odata=verbose` means this is an OData API. There are standardized .NET clients for that. SharePoint provides its own SP-specific client in the Client SDK

Comment: found the answer .

Comment: if it's those 6 lines, yes you did. Otherwise, you are in trouble. The body in the request isn't SharePoint-specific. [OData](http://www.odata.org/) is a standard that allows querying through HTTP. An OData endpoint itself provides its schema which means *you* shouldn't have to know what to put in the `__metadata` tag, or to know that an `UPDATE` operation uses the `MERGE` verb. That's the job of the [OData client library](http://www.odata.org/libraries/) of your choice. The SharePoint Client Library makes this even easier since it knows the URLs needed to access the API, Lists etc

Comment: There's also a [Client library specific to SharePoint Online - Microsoft.SharePointOnline.CSOM](https://dev.office.com/blogs/new-sharepoint-csom-version-released-for-Office-365-june-2018).

Answer (score 0):

Check the code shared by Vadim Gremyachev [here](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/160779/sharepoint-rest-api-c-update-document-metadata), hope it's helpful.

```
var fileUrl = "/Documents/User Guide.docx";
using (var client = new SPWebClient(webUri.ToString()))
{
       client.Credentials = GetCredentials(webUri, userName, password);

       var requestUrl = string.Format("/_api/web/GetFileByServerRelativeUrl('{0}')/ListItemAllFields", fileUrl);
       var payload = new JObject
       {
                ["Notes"] = "Some comments goes here",
                ["__metadata"] = new JObject {["type"] = "SP.Data.DocumentsItem" }
       };
       var updateHeaders = new Dictionary<string,string>();
       updateHeaders["X-HTTP-Method"] = "MERGE";
       updateHeaders["If-Match"] = "*";
       client.ExecuteJsonWithDigest(requestUrl, "POST", updateHeaders, payload);
}
```

Comment: SPWebclient doesn't work for SharePoint online right?

Comment: It's custom class https://gist.github.com/vgrem/7eff63ad7d001d0e4c8f, not server side object model.

Comment: @Lee_MSFT If you propose to use a custom class, make it explicit. Why use a custom class when you can use the official [SharePoint Client Library](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/sp-add-ins/complete-basic-operations-using-sharepoint-client-library-code)? That code was obsolete, and actually bad, when it was written - it tries to emulate OData instead of actually using CSOM or even the .NET OData client library. HttpClient was already available when that code was written too.

Comment: I see there's a [SharePoint Online specific CSOM](https://dev.office.com/blogs/new-sharepoint-csom-version-released-for-Office-365-june-2018) package too